# watch a 1080p movie on 1080p TV on my computer that has a 720p display

Tags: display, resolution, tv, 4k-resolution, 1080p

Good morning everyone,

I have a question. If I watch a 1080p movie on 1080p TV (Or 4K movie on 4K TV), on my computer that has a 720p display, so is it run as 1080p (Or 4K) or just as 720p?

PS: My computer can run a 1080p and 4K movies.

Thank You :)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. While we may be able to guess what "watching on a 1080p TV on a 720p computer" is actually supposed to mean, you'll certainly help others having the same question in the future if you describe your scenario accurately. The key question is obviously, is the 1080p TV connected to your computer, and if so, how (which cable or which WiFi solution) or what else are you talking about. And of course, computer and cable specification may make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If your Graphics Card (GPU) can output a signal at 1080p, then you can output this to your TV. If your graphics card is only capable of outputting a signal at 720p then you will be unable to send a 1080p signal to your TV.

However saying that, some TV's will 'upscale' a 720p signal to 1080p but I'm sceptical that this has any meaningful benifit...